# SSRS in Visual Studio: Matrix grouping takes only the first row

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

Here's the situation. I'm doing a SSRS report in VisualStudio 2010. For some reasons, I can't do it from SQL Server and I can't change the stored procedure I use to get my data either. I receive data in the following format:

```
2013-01-28  4.0         NCI       
2013-01-28  4.0         VAC       
2013-01-30  4.0         NCE       
2013-01-27  3.0         SF        
2013-01-27  5.0         CSST      
2013-01-29  1.0         SF        
2013-01-29  2.0         NCE
```

I want to make a matrix and group it by date to get something like this:

```
Date        Amount      Code
2013-01-27  
            3.0         SF        
            5.0         CSST   
2013-01-28  
            4.0         NCI       
            4.0         VAC  
2013-01-29  
            1.0         SF        
            2.0         NCE      
2013-01-30  
            4.0         NCE
```

This looks like a simple task but all the tutorials I tried ended up giving me only the first row of each date. I'm quite confused as I have no idea what I could be doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a **Matrix**, this could just be displayed as a **Table**.

Add a **Group** to the **Table** based on *Date*, then display *Amount* and *Code* in the **Table** detail row.

Comment: Oh right, a table. It works now. Thanks, I can't believe I never saw that.

Comment: Great, glad it helped! If you find an answer useful or it solves your question please consider upvoting or setting it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Can I also use it for my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23248421/how-to-add-column-in-a-ssrs-table-based-on-criteria