# How to add column in a SSRS table based on criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am trying to create a SSRS report which has a table to list some data pulled from a query. The current table in SSRS looks like this:

```
LAST NAME     FIRST NAME   TITLE    START          END
morrow        diane        pcp      12/15/2009     1/15/2011
morrow        diane        pcp      5/15/2011      6/12/2013
morrow        diane        pcp      7/9/2013       12/11/2014
doe           jane         obgyn    10/12/2013     9/12/2014
ainswor       michael      opt      3/14/2008      4/23/2011
ainswor       michael      opt      6/6/2012       9/2/2014
```

My SQL query just gets each record and adds it as a row.

What I am looking to do is, in my SSRS table, I would like to use a function and expand the START and END column based on how many times each record appears, so for example, I would like to modify my SSRS table to display like the following:

```
LAST NAME     FIRST NAME   TITLE    START          END           START       END         START       END
morrow        diane        pcp      12/15/2009     1/15/2011     5/15/2011   6/12/2013    7/9/2013    12/11/2014
doe           jane         obgyn    10/12/2013     9/12/2014
ainswor       michael      opt      3/14/2008      4/23/2011     6/6/2012    9/2/2014
```

Is that possible in SSRS? Or do I have to modify the SQL query?

**UPDATE**:

What I have so far in my Matrix:
[image]

The output is this:
[image]

For the last entity there are two entries:

```
DateOfLastCredentialing      CredentialingExpiration
2007-12-24                   2010-12-23
2013-10-14                   2014-04-24
```

But as you can see it is only showing one.

How do I fix it so it shows both or as many each entity has?

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish the dynamic columns in SSRS by using a Matrix (a type of Tablix), though you may need to modify your query so that you have a convenient field to create your column grouping on.  If you've never created a matrix in SSRS before, you might consider using the wizard (Visual Studio Project = Add New Report, Report Builder = Insert Table Wizard), and putting your start/end date grouping field into the Column groups, and whatever other fields you need into the row groups.  Take a look at the table that the wizard creates to get an understanding of how the column grouping behaves.

Comment: I did the Matrix but it only shows one record at a time per page. Is there any way to make it so it continue to show records until it has to go to the next page?

Comment: Check your paging settings - it sounds like you may have accidentally applied a grouping/paging rule that's paging after each record group; what you're describing is definitely not default behavior - but it does seem like you're on the right track; once you sort out this paging you should be good to go.

Comment: So far so good. But one issue is I am grouping them by the location. So if one location has multiple entries, it adds only one and doesn't show the rest. Do you know how to fix that? I can show an example if you want.

Comment: I updated my question on how I have it set up and I will also post what the sql query looks like so you have a better idea...

Comment: On my phone at the moment, so I'm actually having a hard time reading those pictures, but I think it looks like you have like 5 different column groups, so try this: open the highest level row group's properties by right clicking it.  Add ALL of the fields you currently have in their own groups into this one group.  Remove the child groups.  You might need to correct your table after this.

Comment: I actually have 5 different ROW group which are on the left and is working fine. I just would like to see the other start/end date for the same entity. Maybe when your on PC again you can take a look for me please... Thanks.